# Can vs 2017 compile to 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

Our shop still uses vs2012 but that package is no longer available from MS.  We can only get 2017.  So, does vs17 have compile parameters that allow it to compile to 2012 compliant code?

TY,

Comment: VS2012 is available via MSDN subscription.

Comment: Compiled programs do not comply to a version of VS. What matters is the .NET Framework you reference in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Compilation compatibility depends on which languages and frameworks you are using.  However, in general your source code and project files should be compatible on either version.

For .NET, as long as you are targeting the same version of the framework, you should get compatible code.  There have been cases where newer versions of the framework have introduced regressions at runtime, but these are generally quite rare.  VS2017 allows you to install different targeting packs for .NET versions from 3.5 (which covers 2.0) to 4.6.2.

I'm less familiar with C++, but there are different versions of the compiler that ship with each version of VS (basically, the latest at the time that VS was released).  I think there's a way to specify which compiler to use, but I'm not sure how.  Again, in most cases, the *source code* will still be compatible, though the resultant binary may be (slightly) different.